# Evaluate JavaScript within ASP.NET Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code and I need to declare the Javascript variable as shown below but Razor syntax is coming in the way.

```
@foreach (var arrivalDateTimeViewModel in Model.ArrivalDateViewModels.Take(7))
{ 
    <script>
        var m = Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arrivalDateTimeViewModel));
    </script>

    <td>
```

How can I do that?

UPDATE:

I have the following code where I convert the view model to JSON and Html encode and store it in the "m" variable. Later I call the selectTime and pass in the "m" variable to the Angular controller shown below:

```
 $scope.selectTime = function (event,m) {

        alert(m); 

        var element = event.currentTarget; 
        $(element).toggleClass("active"); 
    }
```

Comment: You code makes no sense Why would you create a variable `m` and then keep overwriting it in each iteration. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: Don't do this. Instead write your data into a div tag's data attribute, then extract it via javascript. That way you don't need to worry about the right encoding.

Comment: I need to send that object to the Angular controller. So it does make sense! Any other ideas are welcome!

Comment: It does not make sense - you keep overwriting the value of `m`. The value of `m` will be the value of the last `arrivalDateTimeViewModel` object. And you should never write inline scripts like that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am loading the page using ASP.NET Razor syntax and then when the person click the button I need to send the model to the Angular controller.

Comment: What button, what controller? You have not given enough info to understand what your trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated the original question.

Comment: Still not clear (and I don't use angular but you should tag the question with it). If you want to store the model in a variable, use `var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ArrivalDateViewModels.Take(7))';` between a single `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page which creates a javascript array of your objects which you can then loop though or access with an indexer - `var firstitem = model[0];`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the @

```
    <script>
        var m = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(arrivalDateTimeViewModel));
    </script>
```